# Elasticity and Forecasting for Cyclical Data

Tags: regression, time-series

I'm looking at a set of time series data.  Because the data is a time series data, there's also seasonality within it.  I believe this is impacting my elasticity (showing at unit elasticity @ 1.08).

Would it make sense to use this elasticity, calculate the % change in disconnects (I have historicals and forecasts), previous spend $, and the elasticity to project the forecasted spend?  Is this a way to optimize?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us a plot, tell us what the variables are and how they were measured... and give us a precise explanation of the elasticity you care about.

Comment: @Adrian here's a plot of the data.  I want to be able to accomplish 2 things:

Comment: @Adrian here's a link to plot of data. http://i1382.photobucket.com/albums/ah263/janeml06/graphs_zpstxm2dle1.png  I want to be able to accomplish 2 things:  1. Use retention credits to predict disconnects  2. Examine the efficacy of retention credits.    Thanks!